# unable to load whole data from mongodb atlas using python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a python program to fetch data in a collection from mongodb atlas but i am able to view only 10 data using the below python code

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://####:#####@cluster0.0gdmi0s.mongodb.net/retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.test
collection = db.user.find()
for i in collection:
     pprint(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Might you have 10 users only..

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://####:#####@cluster0.0gdmi0s.mongodb.net/retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.test
collection = db.user.find()
for i in collection:
     pprint(i)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).